# Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix and let $B$ be an $ n\times m$ matrix, so that both $AB$ and $BA$ are defines. Prove that:

Tags: linear-algebra

1. If $\operatorname{rank}(B) = m$, then $\operatorname{null}(BA) = \operatorname{null}(A)$.
2. If $\operatorname{rank}(B) = n$, then $\operatorname{col}(AB) = \operatorname{col}(A)$.

Comment: If both $\;AB\,,\,BA\;$ are defined, then it **must be** $\;m=n\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio perhaps OP meant $B$ is $n \times m$...

Comment: He better, @Omnomnomnom...otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: Yes I meant n x m and I fixed it

Answer (score 3):

Since you do not show any work, these are just hints:
$$
BA x = 0 \Rightarrow y=A x ~\text{and} ~ B y =0$$
If rank of $B$ is $m$ then $By=0 \Rightarrow y=0$. Hence $BA x=0$ if and only of $Ax=0$.

For second part
$\text{col}(A)$ is the set of all vectors of the form $A x$ as $x$ varies over **all** possible vectors. $\text{col}(AB)$ is the vectors of the form $A x$ as $x$ varies over all vectors in $\text{col}(B)$. If $B$ is full rank, then $\text{col}(B)$ is the entire space and hence the result.

You will have to fill in all the details.

**Added based on OP's comment**

Let $BAx=0$, and let $y=Bx$. Then $By=0$. There are two possibilities:

1. $y=0$. In this case $x$ is in the null space of $A$.
2. $y \neq 0$. In this case $x$ is **not** in the null space of $A$, but $y$ is in the null space of $B$.

From 1. null space of $A$ is contained in null space of $AB$.

If $B$ is full rank, then 2. is not possible. and in this case null space of $A$ is equal to null space of $B$.

Similar argument for column space.

Comment: Okay, I know that if x<= b and b<= x then x = b. So, I've solved that null A is contained in null BA. I'm having trouble proving that null BA is contained in null A. Same thing for the second part. I've proved that col AB is contained in col A. But I need to prove that col A is contained in col AB.